# How to add a widget area between blog posts in Genesis Framework?

Tags: posts, widgets, blog, genesis-theme-framework

What's the code for adding a widget area between my blog posts?   Specifically I want to put one widget area inbetween after the first 3 posts of my blog?

Answer (score 0):

This thread - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-put-adsense-after-first-topic - explains how to add something after the first post so I would assume you could change the 1 to a 3 to have it display after the third?

And this page explains how to add a widgetized area: http://quirm.net/2011/09/15/widgetizing-any-page/

So you would put the php for the dynamic sidebar where the first post tells you to add the adsense code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the above answer, and specifically for Genesis Framework...

1. Register sidebar (using `register_sidebar`) so you can place widgets in it.  For example:

   ```
   register_sidebar( array(  'id' => 'after_post',
    'name' => __( 'After Post', 'childtheme' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the after post section.', 'childtheme' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => ''
    ));
   ```
2. Show the sidebar in the genesis_after_post or genesis_after_post_content hook using genesis_widget_area.  For example:

   genesis_widget_area( 'after_post', array( 'before' => '' ) );
3. Style as necessary, i.e. .after-post { ... }
4. Place text widget, or whatever else, and test.